# Is "As of August 2019, Paley has been residing in a second-storey apartment near the shore on the island of Ibiza for the last 17 years." correct?

Tags: tense

*As of August 2019, Paley has been residing in a second-storey apartment near the shore on the island of Ibiza for the last 17 years.*

I am writing a biography of this person. I wrote the sentence above but strikes me as cumbersome, perhaps not correct. I would use *since* instead of ***for the last 17 years***, but I am very reluctant to do this in this case, since I do not have enough detailed sources. The person I am writing about talks about ***the last 17 years***, but I do not have any sources about the date  of onset of his living in Ibiza. It is the time aspect that is the most important to convey, the rest is parenthetical.
Am I obliged to use present tenses after ***As of ..*** ? Is the sentence correct?

Answer (score 2):

The sentence *is* cumbersome, and seems undecided as to what it wants to say: is it about how long Paley has lived there, the location of the apartment, or an explanation that Ibiza is an island?

I would revise it to

> Paley has been residing in Ibiza since August 2002, in a second floor apartment overlooking the island's shore.

Comment: overlooking the water, sea or shore.

Comment: @Lambie yes omitting "island's" is probably better, but OP seemed to want it.

Comment: @Weather Vane : I already edited the question in response to your answer

Comment: Re the edit: if you are unsure exactly how long, then avoid the very precise "as of August 2019 ...  for the last 17 years". My answer would have written "...since around 2002..." One major flaw in your sentence, is that the first and last clause (about the date/time) are separated by all the detail. I changed that to a date, because in a few months time your information will look odd.